# Testing firestore rules against emulator fails with reason: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Tags: typescript, npm, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security, firebase-tools

I am trying to set up unit tests for my firestore rules.

Since I am using typescript and jest for testing, I tried to edit [this](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-testing/blob/master/unit-test-security-rules-v9/test/firestore.spec.js) example but it seems like I missed something.

This is my file:

```
import { readFileSync } from 'fs-extra'

import * as firebase from '@firebase/rules-unit-testing'
import { getDoc, setDoc, setLogLevel } from 'firebase/firestore'

describe('Firestore Rules', () => {
    let testEnv: firebase.RulesTestEnvironment;
    beforeAll(async () => {
        testEnv = await firebase.initializeTestEnvironment({
            firestore: { rules: readFileSync('../firestore.rules', 'utf8') },
            projectId: 'myproject',
            hub: { host: 'localhost', port: 4000 },
        });
    });

    afterAll(async () => {
        await testEnv.cleanup();
    });

    beforeEach(async () => {
        await testEnv.clearFirestore();
    });


    test('noone should have access to user document', async function () {
        // Setup: Create documents in DB for testing (bypassing Security Rules).
        await testEnv.withSecurityRulesDisabled(async (context) => {
            const testdoc = context.firestore().collection('users').doc('user1234');
            await setDoc(testdoc, { test: 'test1' });
        });

        const unauthedDb = testEnv.unauthenticatedContext().firestore();

        // Then test security rules by trying to read it using the client SDK.
        const testdoc = unauthedDb.collection('users').doc('user1234');

        await firebase.assertFails(getDoc(testdoc));

    });
});
```

This is my rules file:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /users/{userId} {
       allow read, write: if false;
    }
  }
}
```

When I try to run the test, I get this error :

```
 FAIL  src/tests/rules.test.ts
  ●  Firestore Rules › noone should have access to user document

    FetchError: invalid json response body at http://localhost:4000/emulators reason: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

      at node_modules/@firebase/rules-unit-testing/node_modules/node-fetch/lib/index.js:272:32
```

So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I tried reproducing your issue by cloning the repository and changed the code in `firestore.spec.js` and `firestore.rules` to match what you shared in the post., then i ran `firebase emulators:exec --only firestore "npm run test-firestore"` as explained in the `README`.   
However I didn't observe the behaviour you described, instead it returned 3 passed and 3 fails with an error code for every fail. Then it returned the npm error `code ELIFECYCLE`.  I'm not sure if my result is expected, could you please provide reproduction steps?

Comment: I am using a rules.test.ts. When I use 
firebase emulators:exec --only firestore "npm test rules.test.ts"
The tests time out (I was running these tests from my terminal before, so I guess thats progress)

Comment: So the problem I described probably occured because I didn't use the firebase emulators:exec --only firestore "npm test rules.test.ts" command. 

I thought the test environment would listen to active emulators on my ports